# mysql - Convert SQL query to Rails2 ActiveRecord query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

i have following sql query, i want to convert it to rails 2 ActiveRecord query.

```
SELECT sa.emp_id AS id,sa.emp_name AS Name, 
    sa.emp_supv AS child_id, sa2.emp_name AS child_name
    FROM employees  AS sa 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees AS sa2
    ON case when ifnull(sa.emp_supv,0)=0 then sa.emp_id else sa.emp_supv end= sa2.emp_id 
where sa2.emp_name LIKE '%Nancy%'
```

Comment: I do not this this is possible to convert to ActiveRecord query. But you can use `find_by_sql` for complex SQL statments. http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class